# Remove Previous View In Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I use two Exoplayer in my app:

```
Exoplayer1 in Fragment1
Exoplayer2 in Fragment2
```

When I want go to Fragment2 from Fragment1, I pause Exoplayer1 and play Exoplayer2. But I have a problem:
My previous view in Exoplayer1 is in my Exoplayer2, like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZRcA.jpg):

But I want to play only Exoplayer2 and not show Exoplayer1 view in Exoplayer2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to remove exoplayerview in Fragment 1

```
        ((ViewGroup) exoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(exoPlayerView);
```

And after it in Fragment 2 add it again